# Getting Invalid username and password message, even though inserting valid values in html through Servlets

Tags: servlets, jdbc

My database : [CLICK HERE FOR IMAGE ::---database values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPz74.jpg)

VALIDATION CODE HERE :-

```
import java.sql.*;

public class loginvalidate
{
public static boolean checkUser(String email,String pass)
{


    boolean st =false;
    try{

        //loading drivers for mysql
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

        //creating connection with the database
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection

        ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/conferencesystem","root","root");
        PreparedStatement ps =con.prepareStatement
                ("select * from author where a_email=? and a_pwd=?");
        ps.setString(1, email);
        ps.setString(2, pass);
        ResultSet rs =ps.executeQuery();
        st = rs.next();

    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return st;
}
}
```

[[CLICK HERE FOR IMAGE ::--- Login page Image HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPz74.jpg)

Login PAGE **SERVLET PAGE HERE ::--**

```
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@WebServlet(name = "Loginservlet")
public class Loginservlet extends HttpServlet {
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String pass = request.getParameter("pass");

    if(loginvalidate.checkUser(email, pass))
    {
        RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome");
        rs.forward(request, response);
    }
    else
    {
        out.println("Username or Password incorrect");
        RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
        rs.include(request, response);
    }
  }




protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws ServletException, IOException {

}
}
```

[[CLICK HERE FOR IMAGE ::--- AFTER ENTERING DETAILS AT LOGIN PAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPz74.jpg)

the a_email and a_pwd fields is not excepting, please help me to successfully verify the probelms, What have i done wrong here, simply telling, i have no idea how to do this, but somehow i got this code for validating the login page which is not working, i think i'm missing something here, and  i am currently learning Servlets. thank you...

Comment: (1) The three image links you have provided all link to the same image.  (2) if you enter a username and password that is definitely in your table but your servlet still says they are invalid, my best guess is that the code in your `checkUser` method that queries the database is throwing an exception, which you catch, write its stacktrace to standard error and then return `false`.  Do you see this exception stacktrace in a log or console window anywhere?

Comment: i don't see any log window over here, but i doubt there is something wrong with my code @LukeWoodward

Comment: You don't say how you are running your web app (e.g. in Eclipse, NetBeans, IntelliJ, building a WAR and deploying to Tomcat, etc.).  Without that information it's difficult to say specifically where to look for an exception stacktrace.  Also, have you tried putting breakpoints in your checkUser method and seeing what happens?

Comment: I think i have to trace it @LukeWoodward

Comment: @LukeWoodward I've solved it..

Answer (score 0):

YEAH I got it !,

The Right Code is :-

```
try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/conferencesystem", "root", "root");
        PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("Select a_email,a_pwd from author where a_email=? and a_pwd= ? ");
        pst.setString(1, email);
        pst.setString(2, pass);
        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head></head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Correct login credentials</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
        else {
            out.println("Incorrect login credentials");
        }
    }
```

[CHECK OUT THIS IMAGE!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyBRH.jpg)